# Transformation of Variables as Marginalisation of Joint Distribution - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, metric-spaces, random-variables, conditional-probability

I am trying to derive some equivalent of the transformation of variables formula. That is, given a random variable $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ is an invertible function, then the pdf of $Y$, $f_Y(y)$, is given by,
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right| \tag{1}.
$$
This result is readily derived by considering the relevant cdf and applying the chain rule. I am trying to find some alternate derivation via marginalisation. The marginal distribution, $f_Y(y)$ can also be found by,
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) = &\int_\mathcal{X}f_{YX}(y,x)dx,\tag{2}\\
&=\int_\mathcal{X}f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)dx.\tag{3}
\end{align}

Assuming that $g$ is invertible, I would have intuitively thought that
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\delta(x-g^{-1}(y)),\tag{4}
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. As such,
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_\mathcal{X}\delta(x-g^{-1}(y))f_X(x)dx=f_X(g^{-1}(y)).\tag{5}
$$
This is obviously incorrect. I believe I am making a mistake in (2), as the joint distribution is potentially not well defined? For context, I have a little knowledge of measure theory. Any help explaining where I made a mistake and how to correctly proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their will be no joint distribution, because $Y$ is fully determined by $X$.

Rather this is basically a "change of variables" chain rule for integration.

$$\int_\mathcal Y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy = \int_\mathcal X f_X(h(y))\,\mathrm d h(y)$$

Where $h(y)=g^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not jointly continuous, but they do have a joint distribution.

Comment: Letting $H^1$ be one-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb R^2$, $(X,Y)$ are jointly absolutely continuous w/r.t. $H^1$. Letting $\mu$ be the measure of $(X,Y)$ on the plane, then the distribution function is $\frac{d\mu}{dH_1}={\bf 1}[y = g(x)]\cdot f_X(x)/\sqrt{1+g'(x)^2}.$